# As Binary literal is introduced in c++14..but it could used in C++98/C++03/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Please see below code snippet it is compiled and run fine in C++03/C++11.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main(){

          int a = 0b1111;
          cout<<"a:: "<<a<<endl;

          int var = 4;
          if(var == 0b0100)
                 cout<<"True----------------\n";
          else
                 cout<<"Flase---------------\n";

          return 0;
 }
```

Output:-
a:: 15
True----------------

Please help me what is the difference in C++03 and C++14 binary literal
Even Binary literal could be used in c++03/C++11.

Comment: which compiler?

Comment: how did you compile it? What compiler? what version? What options did you pass to the compiler?

Comment: I have used the G++ compiler on ubuntu ver- 18.04

Comment: what options did you pass to the compiler? You need at least a flag to tell it to compile it as C++03 or C++11

Comment: i removed the c++17 tag, I am not so sure on the c++-cli tag, is this c++ or c++/cli?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 this has got nothing to do with c++/cli

Comment: compiled with the "g++ -std=c++0x" and confirmed it is build also confirmed with "g++ -std=c++1y" flag, code is running fine with both flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-Wpedantic` compiler option it emits warnings in C++03/C++11 mode:

> warning: binary constants are a C++14 feature or GCC extension

[Binary constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants) are a [C language extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) provided by GCC. Their extensions documentation says "most of them are also available in C++" which explains why it compiles.